# Spring 3 multiple values in checkbox tag

Tags: forms, spring

I have a database table which does not contain a primary id and I need to delete rows using two values in a table so that the row is unique.

For each result row displayed on the jsp I have a checkbox for it.

I need to find out if I can do something like this where I post two arraylists via spring form tags?

`<form:checkbox path="valuesList1" value="${object.value1}" path="valuesList2" value="${object.value2}"/>`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, however you can combine your values into one using special separator, e.g. ":::" and then split them back in your controller.